# indexOF method in a Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, list, indexof

I have the following list constructed:

```
var names_Array= []; 
var names_List= new WinJS.Binding.List(names_Array);
names_List.push({ name: "Joe Dowling", image: "image/Joe Dowling.png", ClientID: "1234" }, { name: "Esteban Flamenco ", image: "image/Esteban Flamenco.png", ClientID: "6666" });
```

I want to be able to get the index of the list where the ID is 6666. My attempt thus far was to do the following:

```
var number = names_List.indexOf('{ name: "Esteban Flamenco ", image: "image/Esteban Flamenco.png", ClientID: "6666" }');
console.log(number);
```

But I am getting -1 (i.e. not found). Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You are pushing an object and searching for a string.

Comment: @MatteoTassinari OOK...so can I search for an object?

Comment: @user2363025 no, using an object literal there won't work either.  You have to write a simple loop to search for your object by property value. Also that's not a JSON list; it's a JavaScript array.

Comment: @Pointy could you give me a basic skeletal framework of what you're describing or point me to a site that can have them

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a search facility tailored to your needs, perhaps like this:

```
function findObject( list, property, value ) {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < list.length; ++i)
    if (list[i] != null && list[i][property] == value)
      return elem;
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
var client6666 = findObject(names_List, 'ClientID', '6666');
```

If a matching element can't be found, the return value is `undefined`.

*edit* — I don't know much (well, anything) about the WinJS APIs, but it looks like those "List" objects aren't just simple arrays. I think you may have to do something like this (no guarantees as I can't test this):

```
function findObject( list, property, value ) {
  var i, elem;
  for (i = 0; i < list.length; ++i)
    elem = list.getAt(i);
    if (elem != null && elem[property] == value)
      return list[i];
}
```

Comment: This may need to be extended so it can apply to entire-object matches. Right now, the OP's example seems to intend to compare all values for matching (of course, functionally, I think it should just be the ID, as you've done it, so I voted you up). Oh, and just from my personal preference: An alternative way of checking "if (list[i] != null)" is "if (i in list)"

Comment: Yeah I don't think `list[i] != null` would work at all...if anything, compare to `undefined`, or `typeof x !== "undefined"`. I can't see a reason why `list[i]` would be `null`, unless there's something special about `WinJS.Binding.List`

Comment: @Pointy Sincere thanks for the help. I keep getting undefined

Comment: @Katana314 I tried using if (i in list) also but I'm still getting undefined

Comment: @ Ian I tried comparing it to undefined and typeof x !== "undefined" but I'm still getting undefined. any idea why?

Comment: @Ian I'd check for `null` (which, because I used `!=`, would also check for `undefined`) as a matter of general good practice. Whether the lists produced in the OP's code would ever have empty entries, I don't know.

Comment: @user2363025 well the problem could be that what you're getting from the API isn't really a simple array of objects.

Comment: @Katana314 well "entire-object matches" are in general quite problematic, because the semantics of the objects in any particular application aren't necessarily apparent from the objects themselves.

Comment: @user2363025 ok good - I just fixed the `return` statement too (so that it returns "elem" instead of "list[i]")

Comment: @Pointy Ahh I see, I hadn't thought of that. I guess my point was that I didn't expect an array to have an empty value in its collection (which `!= null` would check for)...I just thought it was unnecessary when iterating an array. But your guess is as good as mine when it comes to what's in that array/object